# How Arduino tone() was created?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++, atmega16

I am trying to understand how tone function works. seems like I can use tone function in a non-PWM channel as well. can you please explain how tome() function was written? If a timer was used then how that was implemented?

Comment: You can check out the source code of `tone`: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp

Comment: with timer interrupt. tones are 'slow' for PWM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function uses timer interrupts to toggle an output pin.

The timer is set up using the frequency parameter. In the [toneBegin](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/3055c1efa3c6980c864f661e6c8cc5d5ac773af4/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp#L128) function

The pin is toggled for a number of times that is calculated from duration and frequency.

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp